# R: How to Mutate Column and Group it

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not really sure how to describe my problem but I would like to perform a time series analysis on COVID-19 data. Below are my code

```
library(dplyr)
hospital=read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MoH-Malaysia/covid19- 
public/main/epidemic/hospital.csv")
icu=read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MoH-Malaysia/covid19- 
public/main/epidemic/icu.csv")
kv_hosp=hospital%>%
  filter(state %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. Putrajaya"))%>%
  select(date,state,hosp_covid)
kv_icu=icu%>%
  filter(state %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. Putrajaya"))%>%
  select(date,state,icu_covid)
kv_hosp1=mutate(kv_hosp,aggregated_state=state %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. 
Putrajaya"))
kv_icu1=mutate(kv_icu,aggregated_state=state %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. 
Putrajaya"))
```

Based on the code above, I had selected W.P. Kuala Lumpur, Selangor and W.P. Putrajaya state and I would like to create a new aggregate as collectively all these 3 states are known as Klang Valley. It is also more appropriate to analyze data in this way as they share the health care resources.

It seems when I'm trying to mutate the column, the end result will be a new column named `aggregated_state` with all the values as `TRUE`. What is the proper method to mutate in this case?

Comment: What do you want your new column `aggregated_state` to have as the data? The way you are doing it is asking if the `state` value is in the `list` of states you have provided, so the new column will be all `True` since you have already filtered to be in the `list` of states. I guess you need to specify what you want the mutated column include other than checking if it is in the `list`.

Comment: I was trying to create an aggregate value know as `Klang Valley` to aggregate all the 3 states while also having the `hosp_covid` and `icu_covid` values to added up so that I would only have an observation for each date.

Comment: Have you tried:
`kv_hosp1=mutate(kv_hosp,aggregated_state="Klang Valley"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try combining the state values of those 3 states into one (`Klang Valley`) and use `group_by` `summarise` to sum the `hosp_covid` column.

```
library(dplyr)

kv_hosp <- hospital %>%
  mutate(state = ifelse(state %in% c("W.P. Kuala Lumpur","Selangor","W.P. Putrajaya"), 'Klang Valley', state)) %>%
  group_by(date, state) %>%
  summarise(hosp_covid = sum(hosp_covid), .groups = 'drop')

kv_hosp

# A tibble: 7,014 x 3
#   date       state           hosp_covid
#   <chr>      <chr>                <int>
# 1 2020-03-24 Johor                   18
# 2 2020-03-24 Kedah                   46
# 3 2020-03-24 Kelantan                78
# 4 2020-03-24 Klang Valley           331
# 5 2020-03-24 Melaka                  19
# 6 2020-03-24 Negeri Sembilan         90
# 7 2020-03-24 Pahang                  36
# 8 2020-03-24 Perak                   78
# 9 2020-03-24 Perlis                   7
#10 2020-03-24 Pulau Pinang            68
# … with 7,004 more rows
```

You can use the same code for `icu` dataset.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for.